# Connection between java and Flex using blazeds returns error #2048

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I have been developing an application(a website to be more precise) which consists of a flex front end which is constantly sending and receiving data from the back end which is programmed in java. The connection between the two components is being done through blazeds. This worked fine while I was running it locally, however when I uploaded both sides of the application to a tomcat server(online) the following error is being returned when a connection between the components should occur:

```
Channel.Security.Error error Error #2048 
url:'http://localhost:8080/blazeds/messagebroker/amf'
```

I have read around about this error and many seem to getting this error when making connections between different servers, unlike here, where the connection is occurring within the same server.

Could any one enlighten me as to what I can do in order to solve this issue.

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are no longer running on `localhost`. That error is indeed saying that your flex app is trying to contact your services from a different domain than the one it was loaded from. How do you have things configured in your services-config.xml file? The endpoint url should be something like...

```
http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf
```

...with the brackets. It will then substitute the values that you are running from, rather than something hard coded.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The configuration in the services-config.xml was indeed hardcoded, however after changing this it is still returning the same error (with the same url as well).

Comment: Did you actually compile with it? Its been a long time but I think it actually changes the code produced.

Comment: I cant understand, initially I had only changed the url on the server, however now i have done so on my local version, re compiled it and uploaded the whole thing once again. What is even more baffling is that I even attempted to change the url back to a hardcoded one, where I replaced "localhost:8080" with my domain name, yet in all cases the url provided in the error has not changed.

Comment: Hi, i have managed to get the site to change the url in the error, with that said, it still returning the same error this time with my domain name instead of localhost, (much like the static url,I tried in a previous attempt). I also used objectutil to print the fault, and part of that fault is as follows:

Comment: endpoint = "http://mydomain.co.cc/blazeds/messagebroker/amf"
      failoverURIs = (Array)#5
      id = "my-amf"
      mpiEnabled = false
      netConnection = (flash.net::NetConnection)#6
        client = (mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel)#3
        connected = false
        maxPeerConnections = 8
        objectEncoding = 3
        proxyType = "none"
        uri = "http://mydomain.co.cc/blazeds/messagebroker/amf"
      piggybackingEnabled = false
      polling = false
      pollingEnabled = true
      pollingInterval = 3000

Comment: protocol = "http"
      reconnecting = false
      recordMessageSizes = false
      recordMessageTimes = false
      requestTimeout = -1
      uri = "http://{server.name}:{server.port}/blazeds/messagebroker/amf"
      url = "http://{server.name}:{server.port}/blazeds/messagebroker/amf"

Comment: what strikes me odd here is that the uri at the top and that at the bottom are different. Do you have any insight as to what is causing this problem?

Comment: I just realized that the error did in fact change and it is as follows:
Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed: url: 'http://mydomain.co.cc/blazeds/messagebroker/amf'"

Comment: The later problem is somewhat un related to the first. Thanks for the help